# Better waiting syntax in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, syntax, callback, semantics

I have an animation running in the background, and I want to register a callback for when it is done. The animation is not a standard java animation -- it is a c animation that is accessed through jni (so assume for this sake that it is just of type *Object*).

The animation has no *onFinish* method to register, but it does have an *isDone()* method that returns a boolean value if the animation is no longer running. To create the callback, I added a runnable as such:

```
class Foo implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (animation == null || target == null) return;
        while (!animation.isDone())
        {
            //loop until animation is done...
        }
        //execute callback
    }
}
```

This seems like it would be a bad way of doing this - just having a loop run until the animation finishes. That said, my question is: what alternative or preferred ways are there to wait until *isDone()* returns true in order to execute my callback?

Comment: Is there no way to issue your JNI call in a thread and then notify an object when it is done?  Does the JNI call execute in the background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically if you don't have control over the Animation class, and it only provides with isDone() method the only way is what you did (but with Thread.sleep for a certain amount of time, like 10 or 50 ms).

Otherwise, you can organize it using one of the following techniques:

1. [wait/notify](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/wait_notify_how_to.shtml)
2. [CyclicBarrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html)
3. [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change animation class use

```
while(!animation.isDone()){
    Thread.sleep(SOME_TIME);
}
```

But if you can change animation behaviour then at the end of animation(when isDone start return true) add something like this:

```
synchronized(this){
    this.notifyAll();
}
```

and instead while loop you could use

```
synchronized(animation){
    if(!animation.isDone){
        animation.wait();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subscription pattern.  You would register a callback with the animation so that when the animation finishes, it would execute your callback.

Another option could be to use [Futures](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) if your animations are inside runnables or callables.